# How to check validation of a model inside of another model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model that has a collection of other models.

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
..
..
  public List<EmployeeViewModel> Employees {get;set;}
}

public class EmployeeViewModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Username {get;set;}
}
```

Now in my Post method, how can I check if the EmployeeViewModel is valid?

**I will have a dynamic number of Employee's, so if any of them fail validation, I just won't add them.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(CompanyViewModel model)
{
    ...
    foreach(var emp in model.Employees)
    {
       // emp valid???????????
       if(  )
       {
         employeeDao.save(emp);
       }
    }
    ....

}
```

Comment: This will help you for sure http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(CompanyViewModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid && (model.Employees !=null && model.Employees.Count >0))
            {
                foreach (var item in model.Employees)
                {
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Username))
                        employeeDao.save(emp);

                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key isto use `ModelState.IsValid`. That will pick up any data annotation violations e.g. `[Required]` in your class and subclasses.